# ajax url not working when click button

Tags: php, ajax

my url of this page is

> http://localhost/mart/lens/contacteyeglass/lens-yes/4

and root folder of this file is xampp/htdocs/mart/include/contacteyeglass.php Inthis file i have one ajax call here is the code,,

```
$("#precdeyails").click(function(event){

                      var formData = new FormData($('#eyeprec')[0]);
                      alert(formData);
                     $.ajax({
        url: '../../../../ajaxcall/addfullcart.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
             alert('yes');
            window.location.href="login/";
        }
        });     
});
```

ajax `url root` `isxampp/htdocs/mart/ajaxcall/addfullcart.php` `first` alert working `second` not working because of this `ajax url` can you help me  `url: '../../../../ajaxcall/addfullcart.php',` of this..

Comment: gopal i think it dosen't matter and i tried not working ..the issue is this line url: '../../../../ajaxcall/addfullcart.php',  see the url(http://localhost/mart/lens/contacteyeglass/lens-yes/4) and folders please help i tried  with single back directory(../) but not working..

Comment: can you place your html and php in same folder? `'../../../../ajaxcall/addfullcart.php'` is is too confusing.

Comment: yes you need to check the URL?

Comment: also check your `console` instead of `alert('yes');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#precdeyails").click(function(event){

                    var formData = new FormData($('#eyeprec')[0]);
                    var base_url ="<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];?>"
                     $.ajax({
        url: 'base_url/ajaxcall/addfullcart.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            if(data){
            window.location.href="login/";
}
        }
        });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try another ajax format:

this example passes an int to an PHP class.
javascript code:

```
    function callFunc($k){
var xhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("POST", "jstophp.php", false);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("specifyFunction="+$k);
    // alert(xhttp.responseText);

    console.log(xhttp.responseText);
}
```

this is the php class:

```
session_start();
switch ($_POST['specifyFunction']) {
    case 1: dosomething; break;
default: dosomething; break;
}
```

what this does is passing an int to an php class with a switch. inside the switch you can put your functions or whatever you want.
Hope this aids in your troubles.

Comment: and how is this going to help the OP?

Comment: selva, your localhost, what port is it listening to? the default 80 or another port?

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path like below (hope this will help)

```
http://localhost/mart/ajaxcall/addfullcart.php
```

instead of

```
../../../../ajaxcall/addfullcart.php
```

Below is full code

```
$("#precdeyails").click(function(event){

                      var formData = new FormData($('#eyeprec')[0]);
                      alert(formData);
                     $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/mart/ajaxcall/addfullcart.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
             alert('yes');
            window.location.href="login/";
        }
        });     
});
```